# Arguments in Auxiliary Constructor in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to create 2 auxiliary constructors .But not able to do so.

```
class learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor(firstname: String,
                                        lastName: String,
                                        middleName: String) {
  println("This is primary constructor")
  println("Complete Name is " + firstname + lastName + middleName)
  def this(firstname: String) {
    this(firstname, "", "")
    println("This is Auxiliary constructor with firstname")
    println("First Name is " + firstname)
  }
  def this(lastname: String) {
    this("", lastname, "")
    println("This is Auxiliary constructor with lastname")
    println("lastname  is " + lastname)
  }
}
```

Can i do this?

Comment: From the compiler's perspective there is no difference between the 1st auxiliary and the 2nd. How can the compiler tell which one is supposed to be invoked?

Comment: either the number of arguments or their types must be different

Answer (score 2):

You have to have distinct constructor signatures. So:

```
class learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor(firstname: String,
                                        lastName: String,
                                        middleName: String) {
  def this(firstname: String) ...
  def this(lastname: String) ...
}
```

is not possible. For such case it would be better to have either default parameters and named parameters:

```
class learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor(firstname: String = "",
                                        lastName: String = "",
                                        middleName: String = "")

new learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor(lastName = "Custom")
```

or separate methods in companion objects with distinct names:

```
object learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor {
  def fromFirstName(firstName: String) = ...
  def fromLastName(lastName: String) = ...
}
```

Comment: Or a mix of the two: Retain the original constructor and in the companion object `def apply(firstname: String = "", lastName: String = "", middleName: String = "") = new learnMultipleAuxuliaryConstructor(firstName, lastName, middleName)`